# use array output in other class

Tags: java, sdk, cognos-bi

Good day!

I have a method which returns me an array of report names

```
System.out.println(bc[i].getDefaultName().getValue()
```

i want to use array output in other class, how i need to linked method outpud in my array in other class?

Method is:

```
public class ReoprtSearch {
    public void executeTasks() {
        PropEnum props[] = new PropEnum[] { PropEnum.searchPath, PropEnum.defaultName};
        BaseClass bc[] = null;
        String searchPath = "//report";
    //searchPath for folder - //folder, report - //report, folder and report - //folder | //report 

        try {
            SearchPathMultipleObject spMulti = new SearchPathMultipleObject(searchPath);
            bc = cmService.query(spMulti, props, new Sort[] {}, new QueryOptions());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        if (bc != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < bc.length; i++) {

                System.out.println(bc[i].getDefaultName().getValue();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

array in what i want put the array looks like:

```
String [] folders =
```

my trying like:

```
ReoprtSearch search = new ReoprtSearch();    
String [] folders = {search.executeTasks()};
```

Returns me an error: cannot convert from void to string

Give me an explanations to understand how i can related to method output from other class.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `executeTasks` method doesn't actually return anything (which is why it's `void`), and just prints to stdout. Instead of printing, add the names to an array and then return it. Something like this:

```
public class ReoprtSearch {
    public String[] executeTasks() {
        PropEnum props[] = new PropEnum[] { PropEnum.searchPath, PropEnum.defaultName};
        BaseClass bc[] = null;

        String searchPath = "//report";
    //searchPath for folder - //folder, report - //report, folder and report - //folder | //report 

        try {
            SearchPathMultipleObject spMulti = new SearchPathMultipleObject(searchPath);
            bc = cmService.query(spMulti, props, new Sort[] {}, new QueryOptions());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        if (bc != null) {
            String results[] = new String[bc.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < bc.length; i++) {
                results[i] = bc[i].getDefaultName().getValue();
            }
            return results;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Did I misinterpret your question?

Comment: At first I did not understand the meaning of. You showed the way how I can write the output to an array. I'll try to use it to test and find out

Comment: Alejandro, why line `public String[] executeTasks()` in Eclipse
say me what: `This method must return a result of type String[]`
for return `results;` at the end? 
We return `string []` by using `return results;` because you declare results as string in line  `String results[] = new String[bc.length];`

Comment: Edited the response; you need to return null at the end if bc == null